# How to use ::slotted inside ViewCapsulation.ShadowDom mode in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom

I had added `::ng-deep` combinator for referencing a content projected element in my component. But when I switched from default (`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`) to `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` mode, obviously `::ng-deep` not being native Shadow DOM selector, old CSS didn't work.

```
/* This works in ViewEncapsulation.Emulated */
:host ::ng-deep .course-description {
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Surprisingly, When I use `/deep/` combinator (which is removed in Chrome v63 https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing) is working fine for `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` in Chrome v75.0.3770.100

```
/* This works in ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom */
:host /deep/ .course-description {
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Can it be possible to use `::slotted()` inside the component CSS to make it work as before but in `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` mode? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck. ::slotted is not supported by .Emulated. It is however supported by. Native

ng-deep is also deprecated and afaik, there's no planned replacement, yet.

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep).

I'm still not sure, if they are working on a solution or just wants us to forget about it.

Comment: Note that `::ng-deep` is the "least deprecated" option, since it was always a purely angular feature not *directly* based on a shadow dom spec. Most answers you can find for this are a headache ultimately leading to the fact that **Angular does not have a non-deprecated alternative to the piercing selectors**. [You can check up on the deprecation status of these features here](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#index)